# Upper and lower bound of an integral in two ways

Tags: calculus

Use max-min inequality to find upper and lower bounds for the value of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

The answer is $$0.5\leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \leq 1$$

But when same integral's upper bound and lower bounds were found out using limits as $0 - 0.5$ and $0.5 - 1$ the result is different as shown below

$$0.4\leq \int_0^{0.5} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \leq 0.5\hspace{25pt}\text{  and} \hspace{25pt}0.25\leq \int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \leq 0.4$$

adding both we get

$$0.65\leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \leq 0.9$$

Why splitting the integral into two gives better approximation?

Comment: Because you restrict the intervals...I think this is obvious, though perhaps it is not *that* obvious why you get the lower and upper limits you got...

Comment: These bounds are simply lower and upper Darboux sums for different Partitions of $[0, 1]$. Try plotting the function and the approximations, then you should see why the second approximation is better.

Comment: Generally, breaking a problem down into smaller parts then approximating it will get you a better approximation.  This is the idea behind Riemann sums.

Comment: the max and min you can apply to the range are closer together in both cases, so the 'boxes' you are calculating the area of are closing in on the curve - the best thing to do is to try and sketch a couple of diagrams

Answer (score 1):

On the interval $[0,1]$ the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ smoothly (in a Lipschitz-continuous way) goes from the value $1$ to the value $\frac{1}{2}$. If we approximate $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ through Riemann sums, it is not surprising that better bounds come from partitioning the integration range in many parts. We may also notice that:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_{0}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^2}\right)\,dx $$
where the new integrand function has a smaller variation on its integration range than the original one, so it is better suited for estimating the integral through Riemann sums. Additionally, it is a concave function, so the approximations coming from the rectangle/trapezoid method are upper/lower bounds for the integral due to the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality). If we perform that "symmetrization trick" once more, then consider a Taylor expansion in the origin, we get:
$$ I \approx \int_{0}^{1/2}\left(\frac{31}{20}+\frac{x}{8}-\frac{503 x^2}{4000}\right)\,dx = \frac{75397}{96000}$$
that is a pretty accurate approximation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.